# Is there command line software that syncs two audio tracks

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, sync, command-line

I have a bunch of separately recorded audio and video tracks that I need to sync. By sync (synch?) I mean align the two tracks so that the audio matches as closely as possible. The two tracks are recorded from different mics (a boom mic attached to a sound recorder and the built in crappy mic on a camera), so they're not exactly the same.

I can do it with Resolve or Premiere etc., but using a GUI app is soo tedious. I feel like this is the sort of thing that ffmpeg should be able to do, but I can't find anything.

Are there any command line programs that will sync two clips using their audio?

Comment: Any distinctive sounds present - clapper?

Comment: That's what http://www.redgiant.com/products/pluraleyes/ does. Not free though.

Comment: Not command-line either. I want something I can automate. @Mulvya, no clapper.

Comment: sync amount would be guessed out of nowhere or provided by user?

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol synched by audio. Premier and Resolve and FCP use some sort of algorithm that matches the timing of the two clips by comparing the audio. I would have thought it's the kind of thing that would exist as FOSS.

Comment: I'm also interested in this sort of thing.  I usually edit video using https://www.mltframework.org/

Comment: There's this, but I don't think it quite does what I want: https://github.com/google/audio-sync-kit